# Trying to cancel execution and delete file using ffmpeg C API

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, memory-leaks, io

The code below is a class that handle the conversion of multiples images, through `add_frame()` method, into a GIF with `encode()`. It also use a filter to generate and apply the palette. The usage is like this:

**Code call example**

```
std::unique_ptr<px::GIF::FFMPEG> gif_obj = nullptr;
try
{
    gif_obj = std::make_unique<px::GIF::FFMPEG>({1000,1000}, 12, "C:/out.gif",
              "format=pix_fmts=rgb24,split [a][b];[a]palettegen[p];[b][p]paletteuse");

    // Example: a simple vector of images (usually process internally)
    for(auto img : image_vector)
         gif_obj->add_frame(img);

    // Once all frame were added, encode the final GIF with the filter applied.
    gif_obj->encode();
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    // An error occured! We must close FFMPEG properly and delete the created file.
    gif_obj->cancel();
}
```

I have the following issue. If the code for any reason throw an exception, I call `ffmpeg->cancel()` and it supposes to delete the GIF file on disk. But this is never working, I assume there is a lock on the file or something like that. So here are my question:

**What is the proper way to close/free ffmpeg object in order to remove the file afterward ?**

---

**Full class code below**

**Header**

```
// C++ Standard includes    
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


// 3rd Party incldues
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libavfilter/buffersrc.h"
#include "libavfilter/buffersink.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"
}
#endif

#define FFMPEG_MSG_LEN 2000

namespace px
{
    namespace GIF
    {
        class FFMPEG
        {
        public:
            FFMPEG(const px::Point2D<int>& dim,
                   const int framerate,
                   const std::string& filename,
                   const std::string& filter_cmd);

            ~FFMPEG();

            void add_frame(pxImage * const img);
            void encode();
            void cancel();

        private:

            void init_filters();            // Init everything that needed to filter the input frame.
            void init_muxer();              // The muxer that creates the output file.
            void muxing_one_frame(AVFrame* frame);
            void release();

            int _ret = 0;                   // status code from FFMPEG.
            char _err_msg[FFMPEG_MSG_LEN];  // Error message buffer.


            int m_width = 0;                // The width that all futur images must have to be accepted.
            int m_height = 0;               // The height that all futur images must have to be accepted.

            int m_framerate = 0;            // GIF Framerate.
            std::string m_filename = "";    // The GIF filename (on cache?)
            std::string m_filter_desc = ""; // The FFMPEG filter to apply over the frames.

            bool as_frame = false;

            AVFrame* picture_rgb24 = nullptr;           // Temporary frame that will hold the pxImage in an RGB24 format (NOTE: TOP-LEFT origin)

            AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = nullptr;        // ouput format context associated to the 
            AVCodecContext* o_codec_ctx = nullptr;      // output codec for the GIF

            AVFilterGraph* filter_graph = nullptr;      // filter graph associate with the string we want to execute
            AVFilterContext* buffersrc_ctx = nullptr;   // The buffer that will store all the frames in one place for the palette generation.
            AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx = nullptr;  // The buffer that will store the result afterward (once the palette are used).

            int64_t m_pts_increment = 0;
        };
    };
};
```

**ctor**

```
px::GIF::FFMPEG::FFMPEG(const px::Point2D<int>& dim,
                        const int framerate,
                        const std::string& filename,
                        const std::string& filter_cmd) :
    m_width(dim.x()),
    m_height(dim.y()),
    m_framerate(framerate),
    m_filename(filename),
    m_filter_desc(filter_cmd)
{
#if !_DEBUG
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET); // Set the FFMPEG log to quiet to avoid too much logs.
#endif

    // Allocate the temporary buffer that hold the ffmpeg image (pxImage to AVFrame conversion).
    picture_rgb24 = av_frame_alloc();
    picture_rgb24->pts = 0;
    picture_rgb24->data[0] = NULL;
    picture_rgb24->linesize[0] = -1;
    picture_rgb24->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    picture_rgb24->height = m_height;
    picture_rgb24->width = m_width; 

    if ((_ret = av_image_alloc(picture_rgb24->data, picture_rgb24->linesize, m_width, m_height, (AVPixelFormat)picture_rgb24->format, 24)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to allocate the AVFrame for pxImage conversion with error: " +
                             std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)),
                             "GIF::FFMPEG CTOR");   

    //printf("allocated picture of size %d, linesize %d %d %d %d\n", _ret, picture_rgb24->linesize[0], picture_rgb24->linesize[1], picture_rgb24->linesize[2], picture_rgb24->linesize[3]);

    init_muxer();   // Prepare the GIF encoder (open it on disk).
    init_filters(); // Prepare the filter that will be applied over the frame.

    // Instead of hardcoder {1,100} which is the GIF tbn, we collect it from its stream.
    // This will avoid future problem if the codec change in ffmpeg.
    if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > 0)
        m_pts_increment = av_rescale_q(1, { 1, m_framerate }, ofmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base);
    else
        m_pts_increment = av_rescale_q(1, { 1, m_framerate }, { 1, 100 });
}
```

**FFMPEG Initialization (Filter and muxer)**

```
void px::GIF::FFMPEG::init_filters()
{
    const AVFilter* buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    const AVFilter* buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");

    AVRational time_base = { 1, m_framerate };
    AVRational aspect_pixel = { 1, 1 };

    AVFilterInOut* inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut* outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    try
    {
        if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to 'init_filters' could not allocated the graph/filters.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");

        char args[512];
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
                 "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
                 m_width, m_height,
                 picture_rgb24->format,
                 time_base.num, time_base.den,
                 aspect_pixel.num, aspect_pixel.den);

        if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in", args, nullptr, filter_graph) < 0)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to create the 'source buffer' in init_filer method.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");


        if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out", nullptr, nullptr, filter_graph) < 0)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to create the 'sink buffer' in init_filer method.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");

        // GIF has possible output of PAL8.
        enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_PAL8, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };

        if (av_opt_set_int_list(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts", pix_fmts, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN) < 0)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to set the output pixel format.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");

        outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
        outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
        outputs->pad_idx = 0;
        outputs->next = nullptr;

        inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
        inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
        inputs->pad_idx = 0;
        inputs->next = nullptr;

        // GIF has possible output of PAL8. 
        if (avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, m_filter_desc.c_str(), &inputs, &outputs, nullptr) < 0)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to parse the filter graph (bad string!).", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");

        if (avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, nullptr) < 0)
            throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to configure the filter graph (bad string!).", "GIF::FFMPEG init_filters");

        avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
        avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        // Catch exception to delete element.
        avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
        avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);
        throw e; // re-throuw
    }
}


void px::GIF::FFMPEG::init_muxer()
{
    AVOutputFormat* o_fmt = av_guess_format("gif", m_filename.c_str(), "video/gif");

    if ((_ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, o_fmt, "gif", m_filename.c_str())) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error(std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)) + " allocate output format.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_muxer");

    AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_GIF);
    if (!codec) throw px::GIF::Error("Could to find the 'GIF' codec.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_muxer");

#if 0
    const AVPixelFormat* p = codec->pix_fmts;
    while (p != NULL && *p != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        printf("supported pix fmt: %s\n", av_get_pix_fmt_name(*p));
        ++p;
    }
#endif

    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, codec);

    AVCodecParameters* codec_paramters = stream->codecpar;
    codec_paramters->codec_tag = 0;
    codec_paramters->codec_id = codec->id;
    codec_paramters->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    codec_paramters->width = m_width;
    codec_paramters->height = m_height;
    codec_paramters->format = AV_PIX_FMT_PAL8;

    o_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(o_codec_ctx, codec_paramters);

    o_codec_ctx->time_base = { 1, m_framerate };

    if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        o_codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    if ((_ret = avcodec_open2(o_codec_ctx, codec, NULL)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error(std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)) + " open output codec.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_muxer");

    if ((_ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, m_filename.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error(std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)) + " avio open error.", "GIF::FFMPEG init_muxer");

    if ((_ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error(std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)) + " write GIF header", "GIF::FFMPEG init_muxer");

#if _DEBUG
    // This print the stream/output format.
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, -1, m_filename.c_str(), 1);
#endif
}
```

**Add frame (usually in a loop)**

```
void px::GIF::FFMPEG::add_frame(pxImage * const img)
{
    if (img->getImageType() != PXT_BYTE || img->getNChannels() != 4)
        throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to 'add_frame' since image is not PXT_BYTE and 4-channels.", "GIF::FFMPEG add_frame");

    if (img->getWidth() != m_width || img->getHeight() != m_height)
        throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to 'add_frame' since the size is not same to other inputs.", "GIF::FFMPEG add_frame");

    const int pitch = picture_rgb24->linesize[0];
    auto px_ptr = getImageAccessor<pxUChar_C4>(img);

    for (int y = 0; y < m_height; y++)
    {
        const int px_row = img->getOrigin() == ORIGIN_BOT_LEFT ? m_height - y - 1 : y;
        for (int x = 0; x < m_width; x++)
        {
            const int idx = y * pitch + 3 * x;
            picture_rgb24->data[0][idx] = px_ptr[px_row][x].ch[PX_RE];
            picture_rgb24->data[0][idx + 1] = px_ptr[px_row][x].ch[PX_GR];
            picture_rgb24->data[0][idx + 2] = px_ptr[px_row][x].ch[PX_BL];
        }
    }

    // palettegen need a whole stream, just add frame to buffer.
    if ((_ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, picture_rgb24, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error("Failed to 'add_frame' to global buffer with error: " +
                             std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)),
                             "GIF::FFMPEG add_frame");

    // Increment the FPS of the picture for the next add-up to the buffer.      
    picture_rgb24->pts += m_pts_increment;

    as_frame = true;
}
```

**Encoder (final step)**

```
void px::GIF::FFMPEG::encode()
{
    if (!as_frame)
        throw px::GIF::Error("Please 'add_frame' before running the Encoding().", "GIF::FFMPEG encode");

    // end of buffer
    if ((_ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, nullptr, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF)) < 0)
        throw px::GIF::Error("error add frame to buffer source: " + std::string(av_make_error_string(_err_msg, FFMPEG_MSG_LEN, _ret)), "GIF::FFMPEG encode");

    do {
        AVFrame* filter_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        _ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filter_frame);
        if (_ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || _ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            av_frame_unref(filter_frame);
            break;
        }

        // write the filter frame to output file
        muxing_one_frame(filter_frame);

        av_frame_unref(filter_frame);
    } while (_ret >= 0);

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
}

void px::GIF::FFMPEG::muxing_one_frame(AVFrame* frame)
{
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(o_codec_ctx, frame);
    AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    av_init_packet(pkt);

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(o_codec_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        }

        av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
    }
    av_packet_unref(pkt);
}
```

**DTOR, Release and Cancel**

```
px::GIF::FFMPEG::~FFMPEG()
{
    release();
}


void px::GIF::FFMPEG::release()
{
    // Muxer stuffs
    if (ofmt_ctx != nullptr) avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    if (o_codec_ctx != nullptr) avcodec_close(o_codec_ctx);
    if (o_codec_ctx != nullptr) avcodec_free_context(&o_codec_ctx);

    ofmt_ctx = nullptr;
    o_codec_ctx = nullptr;

    // Filter stuffs
    if (buffersrc_ctx != nullptr) avfilter_free(buffersrc_ctx);
    if (buffersink_ctx != nullptr) avfilter_free(buffersink_ctx);
    if (filter_graph != nullptr) avfilter_graph_free(&filter_graph);

    buffersrc_ctx = nullptr;
    buffersink_ctx = nullptr;
    filter_graph = nullptr;

    // Conversion image.
    if (picture_rgb24 != nullptr) av_frame_free(&picture_rgb24);
    picture_rgb24 = nullptr;
}

void px::GIF::FFMPEG::cancel()
{
    // In-case of failure we must close ffmpeg and exit.
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);

    // Release and close all elements.
    release();

    // Delete the file on disk.
    if (remove(m_filename.c_str()) != 0)
        PX_LOG0(PX_LOGLEVEL_ERROR, "GIF::FFMPEG - On 'cancel' failed to remove the file.");
}
```

Comment: My tip: Never use `new` but smart pointers and for external resources which need clean up, here ffmpeg ressources, write your own RAII wrapper (simple class with free in destructor)

Comment: In C++ part, I always use smart pointers. It just that for the ffmpeg C API, it a bit hard to wrap everything... I don't have that time for that right now. This seems to work, but in case of failure I still have issue and I don't know what must be freed documentation is not easy to understand.

Comment: Vuwox Well I done have the time to read the ffmpeg docs for you. Usually, when ever your got a pointer returned or the function has the word "create" in it, you can expect you have to release it somehow. You only have to write one class for every type of ressource, which uses a different pair of create and free like functions. You can have a member function, or even better overload operator *, to give you the raw pointer to use directly in the ffmpeg function calls. If these 10 to 30 lines of code are to much or to hard, you wont get a memory leak free application any other way.

Comment: I see no C at all.  Why did you tag this with C?

Comment: ffmpeg API is C, but I use C++ on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but finally get it!

I was missing a `avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);` in my cancel method.

Once the file is released from ffmpeg, the `std::remove()` works like a charm.

Note, the `av_write_trailer` and `avio_close` should only be called if the `init_muxer` successfully executed, so I had a member variable to flag success or not. Then, I do the appropriate call in the cancel.